# how to dislay plot in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, streamlit

im doing visualization with streamlit. i want to plot a graphic like this
[image] with this code from jupyter notebook

```
pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps=100)
pred_ci = pred_uc.conf_int()
ax = y.plot(label='observed', figsize=(14, 7))
pred_uc.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='Forecast')
ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.25)
ax.set_xlabel('Month')
ax.set_ylabel('Harga USD')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

what should i write to show the plot like the picture above? before im try using  `

> `st.line_chart(forecast)` and yeah it didnt work.

please give me a solution or reference! thank you!

`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try code like this
`st.pyplot(fig=plt)`
You can look at the streamlit documentation or its components, I'm sure you'll find more there. You can also get help from the blog and the community
https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html#display-charts